# Azure ARM Triggers (e.g. Resource Created, Resource Removed, etc)

Tags: azure

I am trying to find a way to **trigger events on creation/removal of specific Azure Resources**.

My goal is to add and/or remove these resources information to an App Gateway.

Can that even be done? My alternative would be to use a scheduled solution but I would love to avoid that.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

So you can use something like Azure Event Grid where you can listen to events from different types of Azure Resources and then that event could be listened to by a Webhook trigger which then can trigger your pipeline, see here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview